# iOS 13 CollectionView delegate methods not getting called

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, ios13

We have this code in our app which is running fine for all version of iOS except for iOS 13. In iOS 12 and bellow the delegate methods like cellForItemAt and willDisplayCell are getting called without an issue however in iOS 13 only numberOfSections is called and the other methods are not called.

I have looked for API changes in iOS 13 that might be resulting in this issue and haven't found any. Am I missing something for it to work in iOS 13.

Here is my code :

```
class PhotoBrowserView: UIView, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    var photos: [PhotoURL] = [PhotoURL]() {
        didSet {
            photoCollectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return self.bounds.size
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "photoCell", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let cell = cell as! SimplePhotoCell
        cell.thumbnailButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        cell.thumbnailPath = photos[indexPath.item].photoURL.absoluteString
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return photos.count
    }

}
```

This is how I call the photos:

```
class StoryView: ShowPageView, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    private let photosView: PhotoBrowserView = {
       return PhotoBrowserView()
    }()


    override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
        super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)

        if self.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == .compact, viewModel.story.portraitPhotos.count > 0 {
            photosView.photos = viewModel.story.portraitPhotos
        } else {
            photosView.photos = viewModel.story.landscapePhotos
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you setting your `var photos`?  Is your photos `didset` getting called?

Comment: @valosip  I have added that code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In previous versions of iOS `traitCollectionDidChange` method was called when adding the view to the view hierarchy and in iOS 13, UIKit sets the traits of a view when you create it before you add the view to the view hierarchy. as a result `traitCollectionDidChange` doesn't get called and your photos arent set. When your photos arent set your collectionView doesn't reload.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [Keith at UserYourLoaf](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/predicting-size-classes-in-ios-13/) for more detail.  I will share his answers and add one of my own.

As pointed out, in iOS 13, traitCollectionDidChange is not called when a view is added to the view hierarchy.  It will be called on subsequent rotations of the device.  Prior to iOS 13, traitCollectionDidChange was called when a view was added to the view hierarchy.

This change in iOS 13 caused all my controls to be left aligned when the view is first shown prior to any rotations.  They were centered pre iOS 13.

Fix your code by one of the following:

1. Call your trait setting methods in viewDidLoad (basically copy the pertinent parts of the body of your traitCollectionDidChange to a new method you can then call both from viewDidLoad and from traitCollectionDidChange.
2. Follow Apple's guidance to add trait setting calls to one of these methods:

   UIViewController.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

   UIView.layoutSubviews()

   UIViewController.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
3. As the last line in your viewDidLoad method, call your existing method passing nil as follows:

   viewDidLoad() {
      .
      .
      .
      traitCollectionDidChange(nil)
   }

Consider documenting why you deviate for iOS versions.  Otherwise someone happens along and removes your addition that appears redundant while working on older iOS versions.  You may want to consider creating your technical debt for this change similar to this:

```
// TODO: When I quit supporting pre iOS 13, this conditional can be removed
if #available(iOS 13, *) {
   <whatever solution you chose above>
}
```